# Microsoft Visio branching connectors

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007

In Visio 2007, how would you use a connector as a data bus to reach multiple shapes? From what I've read, there is no branching connector. You have to use multiple connectors and that is really messy. For example, this is the only way I know how to depict this in Visio:

[image]

I would like to do something like this:

[image]

Are there any Visio shapes that can do this?

Comment: I have copied your Visio 2007 question, and [adapted it for Visio 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1375744/microsoft-visio-2016-converging-branching-connectors). Is that ok?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For Visio 2007, Use tree shapes to represent hierarchical stages in a tree diagram:

1. From Blocks, drag a tree shape onto the drawing page.

   a.If you want two branches, use a Double-tree shape.

   b.If you want two or more branches, use a Multi-tree shape.

2.Drag the endpoints  on the tree shapes to connection points  on block shapes. The endpoints turn red when they are glued.

3.Drag the control handles  on the tree shapes to create more branches or to change the branch length or position.

[image: Tree Diagram Thank you Microsoft!]

(1)Drag the control handle on the trunk to the right to create more branches.

(2)Drag the control handle at the end of a branch horizontally or vertically to change its position.

Comment: After I've added about 5 endpoints, the control handle disappears. Is there a limit? That would be weird.

Comment: There is a limit (by default) that is 5 because this connector is created a super simple way. All the 5 endpoints are created but they are all lying on the main branch, being practically invisible. If you want more branch you have to go into Develop mode, edit the Connector and using the already existing configuration data you can duplicate those entries that define an endpoint.
I think 5 is a trade-off between speed and practical usage.

Comment: @GKoe Could you please answer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1341399/how-to-add-values-to-the-x-axis-and-y-axis-of-a-cartesian-coordinates-in-visio Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to terminate the connectors with Arrow-heads? I couldn't find a way to do it, although Format Shape for this shape gives you the option for starting and ending arrows.

Answer (score 45):

You can also connect several connectors:

1. Connect two shapes by connector.
2. Add a "connection point" (the small 'x' near the "connector" tool) on the connector.
3. Connect the third shape to the created connection point with another connector.
4. Repeat as required.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer!

Comment: Much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you stack 2, or more, of the trees, you can get more connection points. Set the points so they are not stacked on top of each other, then "group" the back end. They will move together when you move them from the back-main joining area. When you adjust the various branches of the tree, they ungroup, but can be regrouped to fit when you are done with all your adjustments and become one group.